# Distinguish specific widgets in custom ThemeData

Tags: flutter, dart, key, themes

I was wondering whether there exists a possibilty to distinguish between different distinct widgets in an app from within a ThemeData() class. Can I for instance use `key` on a widget to get the same effect as a `class` or `id` in HTML/CSS?

Suppose I have the following code:

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

ThemeData customTheme(BuildContext context) {
  return ThemeData.light().copyWith(
    appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
      backgroundColor: customBlueColor,
    ),
  )
}
```

Is there some way to check the `key` or something else of the widget in this way?

```js
appBarTheme: widgetKeyIs('greenAppBar')
  ? AppBarTheme(
    backgroundColor: customGreenColor,
  )
  : AppBarTheme(
    backgroundColor: customBlueColor,
  ),
```

I would love to hear! I of course know I can apply a custom theme to the AppBars I want to be green, but perhaps this is a cleaner way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

You could probably use [`shared_preferences`](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences), add a shared variable (bool) `isGreenAppBar`. This will help you.

But, the problem here will be that it doesn't change every time you change it from inside the app and changes will reflect only when the user starts the application.

To support this scenario, you can use [`provider`](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) along with `shared_preferences`.

Using `shared_preferences` is an optional if you don't want the value to be stored and restored on app startup.

[This](https://codesource.io/building-theme-switcher-using-provider-and-shared-preferences/) is an example using both the packages. The link had `theme` which in your case can be `isGreenAppBar`.

The question seems to be similar to theming. So, this might answer your question on using a key to change app bar theme.